# MacVim and netrw - Press ENTER

Tags: macvim, netrw

I've set up MacVim to work with netrw for remote editing (yaaay!), but whenever I save a file, I get the following error:

```
:!scp -q '/var/folders/PN/PNhWJAr5GGC0WfeLdFgWV++++TU/-Tmp-/v771493/0' 'remot_host:path/remote_file.css'

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> removes it and I can edit again. I don't know what it is and it's annoying, but perhaps not broken.

Tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized this problem wasn't unique to MacVim and thus looked in the pi_netrw documentation (`help netrw-p10`).

`set cmdheight=3` in .vimrc removes the prompt when saving a file, but not when opening. That is an enough solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably much better to change it temporary, while reading new file:

```
au BufReadPre   * set cmdheight=3
au BufReadPost  * set cmdheight=1
au BufWritePre  * set cmdheight=3
au BufWritePost * set cmdheight=1
```